# Why is my VBA If statement throwing a Type Mismatch Error

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I have a VBA function that I am building for a project and an if statement is continually throwing a Type mismatch errors. Here's the relevant code:

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

With conn
  .ConnectionString = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=SERVER;DATABASE=DB;Trust_Connection=yes;" ' connection to server
End With
    
conn.Open

Dim year_goal As ADODB.Recordset

sls_rep_wb.Worksheets(yy & " MO-MO").Activate
           
Set year_goal = conn.Execute("SOME SQL QUERY THAT RETURNS A SUM NUMERIC")
            
            
If IsEmpty(Range("AY3")) & year_goal.RecordCount > 0 Then ' this line throws the error
    Range("AY3:" & Range("AY3").Offset(0, 12).Address).Value = (year_goal!Sum) / 12
End If
```

At first, I was getting an error that indicated one of the iterations returned an empty record set for year_goal, which is why i added in the record count condition. I attempted to use the BOF AND EOF properties to check for an empty record set as well and they gave the same error. This code throws an error even when the record set is not empty. Not sure what the issue is, please help. Thanks!

Comment: `&` is the string concatenation operator.

Comment: Btw `Range("AY3:" & Range("AY3").Offset(0, 12).Address)` can be simplified to `Range("AY3").Resize(,13)`

Comment: If IsEmpty(Range("AY3")) `And`  year_goal.RecordCount > 0 Then

Answer (score 1):

The operator "&" is only for strings.

The sentence below below:

If IsEmpty(Range("AY3")) ***&*** year_goal.RecordCount > 0 Then

It will should be written like this:

If IsEmpty(Range("AY3")) ***And*** year_goal.RecordCount > 0 Then

References:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/and-operator

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ampersand-operator